# Nodejs Prompt MoreOrLess

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, prompt, display

I am trying to execute a js code on gitbash (the program's giving a number between 0 and 100 and the aim is to guess this number).

It supposed to ask a number input at the beginning, but I have this message instead :
`prompt: nombre:  undefined`

I have to enter after this message to be able to input a number.

This is my code :

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
var max=100;
var min=1;

prompt.start();

var prompt = require('prompt');

console.log('Give a number between 0 and 100 :');
var randomNumber= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
console.log(randomNumber);

function verifNumb() {
        prompt.get(['nombre'], function (err, result) {
        console.log('typeOfResult', parseInt(result.nombre));
        var saisie= parseInt(result.nombre)
        console.log('typeOfRandomNum', typeof randomNumber);

        console.log('nombre: '+ saisie);
            if (saisie===randomNumber){
                console.log("you won");
                return 'you won';
            }else{
                if(saisie<randomNumber){
                    console.log("it's more");
                    verifNumb();
                }else{
                    console.log("it's less");
                    verifNumb();
                }
            }
        });
};
console.log(verifNumb());
```

Comment: You seem to be requiring `prompt` twice.

Comment: Can you hilight me how do I do that ? I have tried to add another one prompt.get(['nombre'], function (err, result) outside of my function but it hasn't worked